# How to update current branch with changes from master using TFS?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, tfvc

I have a project code that uses Team Foundation Server (TFS) for revision control. I created a new branch named `br-feature` from `main` using Visual Studio 2019. Since then, my `main` branch changed. I want to pull all the new changes from the `main` branch and onto the current `br-feature` branch to ensure everything works before I merge changes from `br-feature` into `main`.

I do not see an option using Visual Studio to fast-forward current branch. How can I pull all the changes from my `main` branch into `br-feature` using TFS?

Comment: Is your repo that is hosted in TFS, using git or TFVC? I'm assuming git but you didn't specify and it makes a difference.

Comment: @JonathanDodds sorry. its hosted on Devops and using `TFVC`

Comment: You're using Git terminology for TFVC. You *don't* pull, or fast-forward; those concepts don't exist in TFVC. You *merge* the changes.

Answer (score -2):

From the comments the repo is TFVC. TFS can host TFVC and git repos.

To work with TFVC:

- Ensure that you have a configured and working Team Project connection. (From the 'Team' menu choose 'Manage Connections...'.)
- Ensure that in the dialog opened by the 'Tools --> Options...' menu that in the 'Source Control' section in 'Plug-in Selection' that "Visual Studio Team Foundation Server" is an option. (The plug-in selection should update based on the selected repo.)
- If you haven't already, you will need to connect to the TFVC repo and establish a local workspace. Both branches will need to be mapped to your workspace.
- In the 'Team Explorer' window, click the 'Home' button. In the 'Home' pane, click the 'Source Control Explorer' link to open the 'Source Control Explorer' window.
- In the 'Source Control Explorer' window, when you right-click on a branch in the context menu there should be a 'Branching and Merging --> Merge...' option.

In TFVC branches are hierarchal. The question description suggests that `br-feature` is a child branch of `main`. It should be straight-forward to merge from `main` (the parent branch) to `br-feature` (a child branch).

TFVC is file-based, not snapshot-based like git. Each file has its own chain of deltas. TFVC changesets are equivalent to git commits but are a set of deltas to files.

Because TFVC is file-based, file adds and file deletes are somewhat special. To keep the order of changesets correct, always merge parent to child before child to parent. i.e. ensure that changes in `main` are merged to `br-feature` and `br-feature` is up to date with `main` before merging `br-feature` to `main`. The 'order' is important with how file adds and deletes are interpreted.

With the branch hierarchy the auto-merge logic is able to perform a three-way compare: the current 'target' file, the incoming changed 'source' file, and the common ancestor for both. But the branch hierarchy can be very limiting.

When you choose 'Merge...` from the context menu, the 'Merge' dialog will open.  The branch you clicked on will be selected as the source branch and you will be able to select the target branch. (The merge is from 'source' to 'target'.)

The "All changes up to a specific version" option is what you want to use. It will default to `T` which is the most recent revision (somewhat like `HEAD` with git).

(In the 'Merge' dialog you will see language about a 'merge relationship' - that means there is a parent/child relationship between the branches. You will also see mention of a 'baseless merge' - that means there is no parent/child relationship. The auto-merge logic doesn't support baseless merges. If you do a baseless merge all changes need to be manually merged.)

Comment: @Jay I initially suspected ChatGPT, but upon closer reading I'm not sure that it is. I think it's a hand-written answer that's just very general and doesn't appear to address your question directly. It does give an indirect answer, inasmuch as the solution to your problem is to merge your changes.

Comment: I have never been mistaken for an AI before. Is that why my answer was voted down? I don’t use ChatGPT but my blog is in ChatGPT’s training set.

Comment: @DanielMann if you ask ChatGPT, it will tell you that it generated that text :)

Comment: @Jay ChatGPT did not generate the answer that I wrote. And the answer I wrote addresses the questions that you asked.